# MYSQL SET variable - update records with a number within specified range

Tags: mysql, variables, set, sequence

My MYSQL statement doesn't seem to be working. I used to use this code from time to time to update the group sequencing in my table.

But for some reason, running this just changes all the records for "mach_group" fields to NULL. What it's supposed to do is update "mach_group" with a number between 1 and 11 within that criteria.

Can any of you spot whats going wrong?

```
SET         @grp:=-1;
UPDATE      mailing_new 
SET         `mach_group`=(@grp:=(@grp+1)%11)+1 
WHERE       machinery='1' 
AND         w='1' 
AND         (nw='1' or sw='1')
ORDER BY    zip ASC
```